# What does it mean and how to fix SonarQube Java issue "Cycles between packages should be removed" (squid:CycleBetweenPackages)

Tags: java, architecture, sonarqube, circular-dependency

Cycles exist between packages when there are dependencies of using or importing kind between classes in these packages.

Consider the following example. Let there be 4 classes: `Truck` and interface `Car` in `org.example.car` package and `Navigation` and `CPU` in package `org.example.part`. In packages `org.example.car` and `org.example.part` we have use relations between classes `Truck --> Car` and classes `Navigation --> CPU`. Let's assume that the class `Truck` use `Navigation` class so we have the relationship between packets `org.example.car --> org.example.part`. Then assume that the class `CPU` also uses the `Car` interface, which gives us the relationship between packages `org.example.part --> org.example.car`. Although the class `Navigation` does not use any class of packet `org.example.car` we have a cycle on neighboring classes in packages (`CPU` class).

This example is presented in figure below:

[image: dependency-cycles-in-packages]

When several packages are involved in a cycle, that means those packages are highly coupled, and there is no way to reuse/extract one of those packages without importing all the other packages. Such cycle could quickly increase the effort required to maintain an application and embrace business change.

Comment: And what is your question? I mean you have sent a "question" and an "answer" at the same time.

Comment: @SubOptimal I think the main question is "how to fix"; "what does it mean" seems very well covered.

Comment: Maybe this post explains at least the "what does it mean" http://www.sonarqube.org/fight-back-design-erosion-by-breaking-cycles-with-sonar/

Comment: @SubOptimal This is Q-A style article, answer is provided below as it should

Answer (score 3):

To fix dependency cycle in your packages you should introduce additional package and move couple of dependent classes/interfaces to that newly created package.

This is presented in figure below:

[image: dependency-cycles-fixed]

In our example, let us chose to move interface `Car` to newly created package `org.example.api`. That breaks the dependency cycle and lowers technical dept in our application. Now all packages have dependencies in only one way and it is possible to split them in different artifacts if needed.