# How to solve circular dependency in gradle multi-project build

Tags: java, gradle

Consider the following situation. I have two gradle (sub-)projects called "A" and "B". A defines some classes/interfaces that are being referenced by B. So B has a compile dependency to A. Now A is a web server that should be started with B on the classpath. **How do you achieve that with gradle?**

Of course it is not possible to add B as compile dependency to A because that would mean a circular dependency between A and B. Even adding B as runtime dependency to A did not work because then compile errors in B state that referenced classes from A do not exist. **But why?**

One solution would be to move code from B into A but I really would like to separate that code because there might be another implementation of B later that I want to swap easily in A (e.g. by exchanging the jar in runtime classpath).

Another solution I was thinking about is to separate classes from A referenced by B into a new module and make both A and B depend on that new module. This sounds valid but that would imply to move persistence layer from A to that new module which feels wrong.

Additional information: A is a Spring boot web application with persistence layer, web services etc, B produces a JAR.

Comment: I ended up moving the code from B into A which was the simplest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circular dependencies are a well-known problem when you try to get Dependency Injection. In this case, you have something similar but at a module level

The only way I see you can solve your issue is by creating a third module `C` with the common code (probably the `A` interfaces referenced by `B`)

This way you can compile `C` (it doesn't have any dependencies), `A` (it depends on `C`), and `B` (it depends on `C`) and launch `A` with `B` in its classpath

Comment: I am curious: When I tried to add B as runtime dependency to A, why didn't that work? I mean module A does not have a compile dependency to B. So it feels like not really a circular dependency. Gradle could compile A then compile B then put it results together for running A with B on classpath.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you end up with circular dependency you probably should introduce another entity to break the cycle.

Have a look at my explanation in this other QA article (it's dealing with packages and classes, but idea is the same): [What does it mean and how to fix SonarQube Java issue "Cycles between packages should be removed" (squid:CycleBetweenPackages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899712/what-does-it-mean-and-how-to-fix-sonarqube-java-issue-cycles-between-packages-s)